# plotting coordinates with error bars in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, errorbar

```
X=[5987324.35399918,
   5987324.35399915,
   5987324.35399905,
   5987324.35399913,
   5987324.35399903,
   5987324.35399901,
   5987324.3539991,
   5987324.35399901,
   5987324.35399898,
   5987324.35399896];
Y=[6764823.56000006,
   6764823.56000007,
   6764823.56000007,
   6764823.56000007,
   6764823.56000008,
   6764823.56000008,
   6764823.56000007,
   6764823.56000008,
   6764823.56000008,
   6764823.56000008];

% Graphical representation of error bar with coordinates
figure
err_x1=[5.9090 5.9090 5.9090 5.9090 5.9090 5.9090 5.9090 5.9090 5.9090 5.9090];
err_y1=[5.9090 5.9090 5.9090 5.9090 5.9090 5.9090 5.9090 5.9090 5.9090 5.9090];
errorbar(X,Y,err_x1,err_y1,'o')
scatter(X, Y,100,'k');
set(gca,'FontSize',10,'xscale','log','yscale','log');
```

Cannot able to get the graph.
X and Y are in meters and err_x1 and err_y1 are in milligon.

Comment: What is the question? You cannot get the graph, why do you say that? What is the output of your code, and what is the expected output? Please read [mre].

Comment: I dont get the error bars just the coordinates.

Comment: Could be a problem with the size of the numbers. But first try adding `hold on` somewhere after the `figure` statement and before the `scatter` statement.

Comment: Yaa. its working now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As Cris Luengo stated in comments, you missed a statement `hold on`, hence the call of `scatter` replaces the first call of `errorbar`. Add `hold on;` between the two solves the problem.